# Accessing String Ressources independent from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

I want to build a helper class, which get strings (from strings.xml) by the name of the string.

In this class should be a method with `getIdentifier()` to get the strings by the name. You need the context for this method. Now every time I want to use this helper class, I have to pass the context from the current activity to it. But the strings in the strings.xml file are independent from the activity.

Is there a way to get the application context for this purpose?

Comment: with getIndentifier you can get the id of the String, not the string itself. In order to get the String you needa context

Comment: @jasdefer Strings are independent but they are used in the context of an activity so you must provide context to the helper class

Comment: @Muhannad Yeah I know. But the question is, if I can give the context one time the helper class and use this from multiple activities.

Comment: Actually you cannot use the activity context in another activity but try to pass the application context using getApplicationContext() and let us know if that would work and make the member variable static so you can call the methods whereever in your code

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I will try it and report the results :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply make Context a paraemeter in your method call.

```
public static String getIdentifier (final Context context, int resource)
```

and then use that context to access the resources.

```
context.getString(resource);
```

In order to call that method from your Activity, pass 'this' as context.

```
String example = HelperClass.getIdentifier(this, R.string.example);
```

Altough, it seems as an unnecessary step, given that it's just an extra layer to what you can already do from the activity.

```
String example = getString(R.string.example);
```

Not sure what your plans are though.